# Whether a domain is Dedekind or not

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

We know from algebraic number theory that if $d$ is a square-free integer, $d\neq 0,1$ and $d$ is congruent to $2,3$ modulo $4$ then $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is the ring of integers of the quadratic extension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ hence is a Dedekind domain.

Do the "converse" also hold? I mean, suppose $d$ congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. Can I say that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is NOT a Dedekind domain?

Comment: Not only is ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ not a Dedekind domain when $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, but you can write down an explicit example where multiplication of ideals doesn't admit cancellation: $(2,1+\sqrt{d})^2 = (2)(2,1+\sqrt{d})$ in ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{d}]$. If we could cancel ideals then $(2,1+\sqrt{d}) = (2)$, which is false since $1+\sqrt{d} \not\in (2)$ in ${\mathbf Z}[\sqrt{d}]$. If you can't cancel ideals then you certainly don't have unique factorization of ideals. Note that the calculation is also true in ${\mathbf Z}[(1+\sqrt{d})/2]$, but there $(2,1+\sqrt{d})=(2)$, so no contradiction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dedekind domain must be integrally closed. For $d \equiv 1$ mod $4$, we have that the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}/2 +1/2]$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$.

Edit: As Dr. Leeuwen suggested, I'll add that the integral closure of an integral closure of a Dedekind domain is another Dedekind domain. This is immediately useful in number theory because people care quite a bit about the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and Dedekind domains, of course, have very nice properties.

Comment: And you might add that this integral closure _is_ a Dedekind domain.